# How can I copy/paste from Hyper-V Windows 10 into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server bash?

Tags: bash, windows-10, hyper-v, copy-and-paste

I have Ubuntu Server installed on a Hyper-V virtual machine and would like to be able to copy/paste from my Windows 10 machine into the Ubuntu Server's command line. Is it possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.datto.com/blog/how-to-share-files-between-hyper-v-host-and-guest

Comment: @ChanganAuto That's actually not what I was asking about. I wanted to copy some text from the Hyper-V host to the Ubuntu's command line so I won't have to type everything from scratch.